# Redirect subdomain with subdirectory

Tags: linux, apache, redirect, web

I apologize if this has been asked before, but I couldn't find any relevant info (I found one post that was redirecting all subdomains, but I only need the one).

I need to setup a redirect for http://subdomain.example.com/path/ to http://example.com/path/

How should I go about setting this up using apache? Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: As an additional bit of info, I am also currently redirecting http://subdomain.example.com/ to http://example.com/subdomain/

Comment: This should be a simple rewrite rule.

Comment: You're right. I'm an idiot and the original subdomain.example.com -> example.com/subdomain worked for both cases.